# VBA-Find Word in Row and output the next column

Tags: vba, excel

```
Amt1 Tax1 Amt2 Tax2 Amt3 Tax3 Amt4 Tax4 Amt5 Tax5 Amt6 Tax6
YQ   25    YR   22   QW   25   TR   58   WR   105  AY   125
YR   102   YQ   25   AY   15   YR   152  WR    55  WQ   120
```

In Excel, now i want the output in a column for total of YR, if YR comes 5 times in a row the output should give me total of all 5.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula based solution using SUMIFS

```
=SUMIFS(B2:L2,A2:K2,"YR")
```

Notice the offset in the ranges: Sum Range is offset 1 column to right of Criteria Range

Comment: More like this: `=SUMIF(C19:F23;"YR";OFFSET(C19:F23;0;1))`, but it would work flawlessly and faster than the VBA. Thus it would work for the whole range of more than one column.

Comment: @Vityata why use OFFSET?  Using OFFSET makes the formula Volitile (recalculates the formula regardless of change in input values) and therefore slows down your workbook.  And it is unnecassary - just use `D19:G23`

Comment: @Vityata And see Yoogy's comment to Shai's answer - he wants to sum each row seperately, so my answer as is gives him what he wants

Comment: Yap Even this is a better option ... simple & staright..I used the original one from chris

Comment: @chrisneilsen your option is easy to use & also servers my need... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UDF below:

```
Option Explicit

Function mySumIfs(lRow As Long, Str As String) As Long

Dim LastCol As Long
Dim C As Range

LastCol = Cells(lRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' get last column in current row

' loop through all cells in the Range of the Row selected
For Each C In Range(Cells(lRow, 1), Cells(lRow, LastCol))
    If C.Value Like Str Then
        mySumIfs = mySumIfs + C.Offset(, 1).Value
    End If
Next C

End Function
```

Then, in your Excel Sheet's cell you can just type in the Formula:
`=mySumIfs(3,"YR")`.

- 3 - indicating the row number
- "YR" - the string being searched for

You can also use it from VBA, just use:

```
Dim SumTest As Long
SumTest = mySumIfs(3, "YR")
```

Screen-shot of how it is implemented in my Excel Sheet:

[image]

Comment: but i want the toatl amount of YR, say in 1st row its 22 and in 2nd row its 254 (102 + 152).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a code-for-me site and when you ask such questions you should show some kind of effort for solving them.
Having said that, here is a way to solve your problem with a custom formula:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function OutputMe(rngSelectRange As Range, strOutput As String) As Double

    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In rngSelectRange
        If rngCell = strOutput Then
            OutputMe = OutputMe + rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Check out the Formula solution of @chris neilsen - my comment below it, it is faster.